# Using appropriate algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, logistic-regression, linear-regression

I went through basic concepts of ML algorithms but still had few queries on their advantages over each other.

1. When should we use linear regression vs Neural Networks for regression?
2. When should be use Logistic Regression vs SVM vs Neural Networks classification vs Decision Trees?

Answer (score 2):

If you need something interpretable but accuracy is less important, use the methods on the left side of the question (linear regression, logistic regression). If accuracy is more important, use the methods on the right side of the question (neural nets). SVM is a somewhere in the middle.